# on generators of $k$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m,k)$ be a local ring, and $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and the maximal ideal $m$ is nilpotent. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in m$ and their canonical images in $m/m^2$ generate this $k$-vector space.

How to show that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ generate $A$ as $k$-algebra?

Comment: When you put a hyphen between dollar-signs, so it's inside of $\TeX$, then it looks like a minus sign instead of a hyphen.  Not only is a minus sign longer, but it is preceded and followed by spaces that don't happen with a hyphen.  Observe: $k-$algebra versus $k$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your hypothesis is that 
$$
A=k[y_1,\dots,y_p] \text{ is local, }\mathfrak m^N=0,  k=A/\mathfrak m \text{ and } 
\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2= k<\overline{x}_1,\dots,\overline{x}_n>
$$
By Nakayama $\mathfrak m=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. The chain 
$$
0 \subseteq \mathfrak m^N \subseteq \mathfrak m^{N-1} \subseteq 
\mathfrak m^2 \subseteq \mathfrak m \subseteq A
$$
then gives you the finite-dimensional $k$-vectorspaces $\mathfrak m^i/\mathfrak m^{i+1}$, so by induction it follows that $A$ itself is a finite-dimensional $k$-vectorspace [EDIT:] generated by $1$ and a finite set of monomials of the $x_i$

Comment: Yes. Thank you,Blah.